# How to goreleaser to build sub-folder in github

Tags: go, building-github-actions, goreleaser

I use goreleaser to build in github action.
Because my main.go in `./cmd/tes_cli`, it always show error in github action.

```
repo does not contain a main function.
```

I check the original document, it seems "builds" could works. my configuration could not add `builds`

```
name: Release Go project

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "*" # triggers only if push new tag version, like `0.8.4` or else

jobs:
  build:
    name: GoReleaser build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out code into the Go module directory
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 # See: https://goreleaser.com/ci/actions/

      - name: Set up Go 1.14
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: 1.14
        id: go

      - name: Run GoReleaser
        uses: goreleaser/goreleaser-action@master
        with:
          version: latest
          args: release --rm-dist
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an extra configuration file to resolve it.

Refer https://github.com/kkdai/disqus-importor-go/pull/4/files

```
args: release -f .goreleaser.yml --rm-dist
```

link to another config file.

```
# .goreleaser.yml
project_name: import_disqus_cli
builds:
  - env: [CGO_ENABLED=0]
    goos:
      - linux
      - windows
      - darwin
    goarch:
      - amd64
      - arm64
    id: "import_disqus_cli"
    dir: .
    main: ./cmd/test_cli
```